# How to exclude leads from an imported .csv file regarding to their job title or any other attribute?

Tags: leads, csv, inputfield, data-import

**Hello!**
I am trying to automate the lead importing process to save some time. Usually what I do whenever we have a list of participants to virtual events (**.xlsx**), is a VLOOKUP command to find duplicate leads in our records, and then delete by hand the participants who are students or unemployed.
I have managed to exclude the duplicate ones when importing a **.csv** file, but I got stuck trying to exclude those who are not actively working.

I would like to know if there's a way of doing this using the "job title" imported field. If there is someone who knows the answer for this question, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

First try using Duplicate rules to prevent creation of Duplicate Leads.

Second maybe add a Validation Rule or Check Job title in Before Insert Trigger. This would fail for Leads where the Job Title is blank.

Comment: Thanks! I think validation rules solve this problem. Regarding blank spaces for Job Title, we will try to "educate" them inactive Leads to fill this field with one acronym like "NA" for example, in order to filter information.

Comment: Cool. You should be able to create an Excel for that. But why not use WebToLead if the people already have ipad/iphone or Laptop  ?